# Avalonia DataGrid ComboBox SelectedValue binding

Tags: combobox, datagrid, avalonia

My DataGrid contains three columns. Two TextColumns and one ComboBox. I'm struggling with the ComboBox SelectedValue. ItemsSource is working fine, I see all expected values, but I the SelectedValue is never shown/set.

```
<DataGrid Name="PropertyGrid"
      Grid.Row="1"
      ItemsSource="{Binding ControllerAction.RequestParameters, Mode=TwoWay}"
      SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Types, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                          SelectedValue="{Binding Type}"
                          SelectedValueBinding="{Binding}"
                          PlaceholderText="Select type"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Binding" Binding="{Binding Binding}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGrid.Styles>
    <Style Selector="DataGridRow:selected/template/Rectangle#BackgroundRectangle">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#d7e9fb" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Styles>
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Delete request parameter" Name="DeleteRequestParamMenuItem"
                  Click="DeletedButton_Click" />
    </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

Types is just a list of strings:

```
public static readonly StyledProperty<IList<string>> TypesProperty =
    AvaloniaProperty.Register<ControllerActionPage, IList<string>>(nameof(Types));

public IList<string> Types
{
    get => GetValue(TypesProperty);
    set => SetValue(TypesProperty, value);
}
```

RequestParaemters is a list of RequestParameterDto:

```
public class RequestParamterDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Binding { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What do I need to change that I see the selected value?